# Is there a sharper Golden–Thompson inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities

For any two Hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$, the Golden–Thompson inequality
$$\mathrm{Tr} (e^A e^B) \geq \mathrm{Tr} \, e^{A + B}$$
holds, and it is known to be a strict inequality whenever $[A, B] \neq 0$ [see D. Petz, Banach Cent. Publ. 30, 287 (1994)].

Thus, we can write it as
$$\mathrm{Tr} (e^A e^B) = e^{f(A,B)} \, \mathrm{Tr} \, e^{A + B}$$
where $f(A,B) \geq 0$ is a real-valued function that is $0$ iff $[A, B] = 0$.

My question is whether there are any known lower bounds on $f(A,B)$. Ideally, such a bound would be some function of the commutator $C = i [A, B]$.

---

The naive approach of trying to get something out of the series expansion does not seem to work. In particular, it can be straightforwardly calculated that
$$\mathrm{Tr} (e^A e^B) = \mathrm{Tr} \, e^{A + B} + \frac{1}{24} \mathrm{Tr} \, C^2 + \cdots .$$
However, the subsequent terms can get negative, so it is easy to (numerically) find such $A$ and $B$ that
$$\mathrm{Tr} (e^A e^B) < \mathrm{Tr} \, e^{A + B} + \frac{1}{24} \mathrm{Tr} \, C^2$$
or such that
$$\mathrm{Tr} (e^A e^B) < \exp\left(\frac{\mathrm{Tr} \, C^2}{24 \, \mathrm{Tr} \, e^{A + B}}\right) \, \mathrm{Tr} \, e^{A + B}$$
meaning that subtler considerations are needed to get to a meaningful $f(A,B)$.

Comment: The second displayed equation only works when the traces are $\ge 0$.

Comment: Indeed, the GT inequality is for Hermitian matrices, for which both traces are real and, of course, nonnegative. I edited the question so that it explicitly mentions that $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4587126/bounding-baker-campbell-hausdorff-error-with-commutator-of-exponentials) is plausibly relevant, but not entirely resolved.

Comment: It seems plausible that one can extract bounds that you want out of "A Theory of Trotter Error" ([Arxiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.08854), [APS version with slightly different title but same author list](https://journals.aps.org/prx/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevX.11.011020)). The second paper (page 21) claims that as a function of $t$ that $\exp(tA)\exp(tB) =\exp(tA+tB) + \int_0^t \exp((1-\tau)(A+B))[\exp(\tau B),A]\exp(\tau A)\mathrm{d}\tau$. This might (eventually) be useful for getting the bound you want, though there are some additional steps to be done.

Comment: That is an interesting expression I did not know about—thanks for digging it out! I do not see how to make use of it at this point, though, since
$$\mathrm{Tr} \left(e^{(1-\tau) (A + B)} \, [e^{\tau B}, \, A] \, e^{\tau A} \right)$$
can be complex for $0 < \tau < 1$ when $A$ and $B$ are complex (but Hermitian). So, while the integral of this trace over $\tau$ is positive, lower-bounding it can be extra challenging since the integrand is not lower-boundable.

Comment: OK, knowing that the integral must be real, we can simply work with the real part of the integrand, and it can actually be nicely written in a way that explicitly showcases the $A \leftrightarrow B$ symmetry of the whole thing:
$$\mathrm{Tr} (e^A \, e^B) - \mathrm{Tr} e^{A +B} = \frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 d\tau \, \mathrm{Tr} \left( [e^{\tau A}, \, e^{\tau B}] \cdot [e^{(1-\tau) (A + B)}, \, A-B] \right) .$$
The integrand is a trace of a product of two Hermitian operators, so it is real for all $\tau$'s. From numerical random-sampling checks it appears to moreover be positive, so there is hope.

Comment: Why are you expecting a uniform bound purely in terms of the first commutator? Do you have a specific kind of $A$ and $B$ in mind? What is the Lie algebra generated by $A$ and $B$, is it nilpotent?

You see, in the integral formulae above, knowing the commutator $[e^{tA},e^{tB}]$ for all $t$ amounts to knowing all orders of commutators between $A$ and $B$. You cannot get away with only the first commutator, unless you know more about $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @Bedovlat Having something as convenient as a simple-ish function of $[A, B]$ was just a naive desirable. But the integral representation pointed out by Mark seems to close the door on that since $A$ and $B$ are general Hermitian matrices (so no nilpotency can be assumed) and, indeed, all orders of commutators will have to be accounted for.